# How does this Flutter constructor call work?

Tags: flutter, syntax

I am new to Flutter and as I was reading through the tutorial I saw the following code snippet:

```
// Within the `FirstRoute` widget
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
  );
}
```

Why does the call in the [`MaterialPageRoute`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialPageRoute-class.html) work? I see it requests an object of type [`WidgetBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetBuilder.html), but what we pass is a [`BuildContext`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html). Do the parentheses around `context` indicate a call to the constructor of the `WidgetBuilder`?

Comment: do you want to call parameters immediately when you create an object?

Comment: `WidgetBuilder` is a function that takes one argument of type `BuildContext` and returns a `Widget`.

Comment: builder is an callback function which returns Widget, when you are passing SecondRoute it is a class which containes build function which takes context as an argument and  by the way returns widget so it will return new page with a widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The builder parameter accepts an object of type WidgetBuilder as you say. What is "hidden" is that it is typedef:

```
typedef WidgetBuilder = Widget Function(BuildContext context);
```

So what you've passed is actually an anonymous function that match it.

Answer (score 0):

It is called an arrow function. Actually this piece of code

```
(context) => SecondRoute()
```

can be rewritten like:

```
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)  {
 return SecondRoute();
})
```

And widget builder is a function, which MaterialPageRoute require as a parameter.